# Unity single joystick prefab

Tags: rotation, unity-game-engine, joystick

I would like to controll movement and rotation ans cant seem to find an answer. Im working with 3.4 Unity

Answer (score 1):

Try the good unity tutorial "Penelope". Is a good introduction for characters control.

[Penelope Tutorial](http://unity3d.com/support/resources/tutorials/penelope)